# Android studio, load jar library with transitive dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my app gradle file I have

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This allows me to use the classes inside my library jar files. But what if the jar itself contains a lib folder with jar's inside? Like

```
com.mylib.network/
   classes/
   libs/
        com.otherlib.model.jar
```

I can do:

```
import com.mylib.network.*;
```

but not

```
import com.otherlib.model.*;
```

Is it possible to load the nested libs with gradle? Any other ideas?

Comment: if you library is a jar, I assume there is no way to load transitive dependencies like with a aar lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this work with jars (transitive). But you can simply unzip your jar to pull out the other jar and place both jars directly into the libs folder used by gradle

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you are running gradle, you could execute `./gradlew jarRelease` which will create your project classes.jar and other folder with dependencies (not in jar). Is up to you after to jar the dependencies folder like `com/squareup/okhttp`.

the jarRelease gradle script is this one :

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir

    task.from configurations.compile.findAll {
        it.getName() != 'android.jar' && !it.getName().startsWith('junit') && !it.getName().startsWith('hamcrest')
    }.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }

    artifacts.add('archives', task);
}
```

**To jar a folder :**

```
# Jar .class dependencies 
@cd outputs/aar/ && \
    jar cf libs/com.jar com/
```

**To unjar a folder :**

```
@cd outputs/jar/ && \
    jar xf myjar.jar
```

Note : you could also if you are using ressources create a library project compatible with eclipse using a makefile and using data from aar and jar.